# Javascript - convert numbers to strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program that take your birthdate (yymmdd), replaces the numbers with strings and output your "real birthname".

Problem is that the loop only output the string for the last number typed into the prompt and += with itself. I was kind of hoping it would iterate through the loop and add one string after another in the birthname variable.

(This is my first own code so be gentle) :)

```
var birthDate = prompt("write your birthdate!");
birthDateSplitter = birthDate.split("");
len = birthDateSplitter.length,
birthName = 0;
var i = 0;

for (i; i < len; i++) {
    if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 9) {
        birthName = "do";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 8) {
        birthName = "ka";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 7) {
        birthName = "mu";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 6) {
        birthName = "ssa";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 5) {
        birthName = "tto";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 4) {
        birthName = "ti";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 3) {
        birthName = "le";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 2) {
        birthName = "pa";
    } else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 1) {
        birthName = "bu";
    } else {
        birthName = "vi";
    } 
    birthName += birthName;
}

alert("Your real birthname is " + birthName);
```

Comment: How about `birthname += "word"`?

Comment: Well, `birthName =` overwrites the previous variable. Either use `+=` right away, or if you want to do `birthName += birthName;` in the end, use two differently named variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 9) {
    birthName += "do";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 8) {
    birthName += "ka";
//...
```

but better, you could get rid of `if`s:

```
var birthDate = prompt("write your birthdate!");
var birthDateSplitter = birthDate.split("");
var len = birthDateSplitter.length;
var birthName = '';
var i = 0;
var birthNameParts = ['vi', 'bu', 'pa', 'le', 'ti', 'tto', 'ssa', 'mu', 'ka', 'do'];

for (i; i < len; i++) {
    birthName += birthNameParts[birthDateSplitter[i]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (And I could even understand it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the loop
birthName += "what you want"

Answer (score 0):

```
var birthDate = prompt("write your birthdate!");
var birthDateSplitter = birthDate.split("");
var len = birthDateSplitter.length;
var birthName = '';
var i = 0;

for (i; i < len; i++) {

if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 9) {
    birthName += "do";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 8) {
    birthName += "ka";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 7) {
    birthName += "mu";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 6) {
    birthName += "ssa";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 5) {
    birthName += "tto";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 4) {
    birthName += "ti";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 3) {
    birthName += "le";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 2) {
    birthName += "pa";
} else if (birthDateSplitter[i] == 1) {
    birthName += "bu";
} else {
    birthName += "vi";
} 

}

alert("Your real birthname is " + birthName);
```

Maybe "switch-case" here will be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would have approached that:

```
var birthDateSplitted = prompt('write your birthdate!').split(''),
    nameParts = ['vi', 'bu', 'pa', 'le', 'ti', 'tto', 'ssa', 'mu', 'ka', 'do'],
    birthName = birthDateSplitted.map(function(n) { return nameParts[n]; }).join('');

alert('Your real birthname is ' + birthName);
```

https://jsbin.com/gisubop/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would appreciate some further explanation regarding the third line. What is the purpose of the .map and . join in this case?

Comment: The map function takes every item in the array and does something to it. You can read some more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - a great source of js docs.

What it does in this case: takes every number from an array of splitted birthdate numbers, looks up the corresponding part in the namesParts. After that we have a new array of name parts. To turn it into a single word, we use join, to glue the items of the array into a single string.

Comment: .map seem really useful, will try to remember that one. Much appreciated for the clarification! (MDN was an instant bookmark btw)